# Unable to run java through bat file

Tags: java, batch-file

I set my environment variables correct, and while running `Java <classname>` it is running fine.

But when running the same through a bat file, I'm getting errors like
`java is not recognized as internal or external command or bat file`.

I tried displaying the path and classpath, but everything is fine there. **What am I doing wrong?**

Here is my piece of code:

```
cd\
cd C:\myproject
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;"%PATH%
set CLASSPATH="C:\myproject\sqljdbc4.jar;C:\myproject\jxl-2.6.12.jar"
java InsertRecords %1 %2
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java executable isn't covered in PATH, add it to path

change it to

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\
```

Comment: Could make it clear? java executable means java.exe!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with how you are setting the path variable...take a look at this...

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;"
                                      ^---This doesn't look right
```

Try using something more like...

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin";%PATH%
                                               ^--- Note the change here...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need no quotes in long pathnames in PATH variable.